# Content in the request body is not being received by the controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi2 `Controller` with the following action:

```
[Route("{id:int}/Change")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Change(int id, [FromBody] string description)
{
    var entity = await entityService.ChangeAsync(id, description);
    return Ok(entity);
}
```

And I'm making the request as follows:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("description", descripton)
});

response = client.PostAsync(string.Format("Api/Entity/{0}/Change", id), content).Result;
```

However, the `description` value is not reaching the action and it's always null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Quick tip: look at ModelState to see if there are any errors in it.

Comment: @Erndob No errors. There's only one entry and that's the id being passed in the path.

Comment: Maybe your client is expecting json, not FormContent? Since it's WebApi. Not sure if PostAsync automatically changes the content-type header to form when you give the body as Form. It could be that you have set the content header on your client itself, and then it doesn't automatically change it when you go from Json to Form.

Comment: Oh also, your action doesn't have the HttpPost attribute.

Comment: @Erndob You're right. Client expects json not FormContent. Changed it accordingly.

Comment: I'll write an answer so that you can accept it and I can get the sweet karma :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HttpClient is expecting Json, not form content. To change that, you need to change `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. With this, the api should be able to negotiate the content type correctly and parse the data.